# Is there a term used to signify one dialect retains more older words, or conversely, that one adopts more neologisms?

Tags: terminology, language-change

Sometimes English retains an old word and updates it meaning, like *bottle* which originally meant *[wineskin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bottle).* Sometimes it creates a new word for a new innovation, like [television](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=television). There appears to be a tendency in British English to retain some older words for new purposes where they have been replaced in American English with neologisms. For example *torch/flashlight,* *chemist/pharmacist,* *dustbin/garbage can,* *fire/heater.*

Is there a term that we could use to say one dialect retains more of the older words, or conversely, that one adopts more neologisms?

Examples sentences where it would be used:

British English is a ______ dialect, unlike American English. (or vice versa)

Or, British English is more ________ than American English. (or vice versa)

Comment: Your title is one question; it is about  old words getting new meaning. The body of your post is another; it is about renewal of the vocabulary, about  creating new terms for the existing ones or retaining the traditional ones. The two questions  are not too closely related. Otherwise, would I not be getting the sense of your words clearly?

Comment: I've edited the title. I didn't want it to be too long, but it comes in just under the character limit.

Comment: Not really the focus of your Q but I'm not sure about some of those examples - *pharmacist* dates from the middle ages, I'm not seeing how *dustbin* fits, *fire* in *electric fire* doesn't just mean *heater* (it referred to the type of heater that was supposed to look like a real fire), *boiler* is non-literal but how do we know it was literal in days of yore... plus *water heater* is used - is *boiler* never used in AmE? You may be right that there's a difference but I'm only seeing one clear example here.

Comment: @rchivers: Is _pharmacist_ really from the middle ages? It doesn't sound like it. Any reference?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian In fairness the headword I was looking at was *pharmacy* - etymonline says the meaning *the use or administration of drugs* is from c. 1400. Looking again there is a separate entry for *pharmacist*, which says *"a druggist, apothecary, one skilled in pharmacy," 1811; see pharmacy + -ist. Replaced obsolete pharmacian (1720). Pharmaceutist in this sense is attested from 1785. The Latin word was pharmacopola, the Greek pharmakopoles*. idk how reliable this source is.

Comment: My father (born 1907, no American connections) used to say 'flashlight'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Mine too, but wasn't that the thing on a camera? I think that's the only time _I_ heard the word.

Comment: @rchivers: Thanks. I just couldn't see the Wife of Bath going to the pharmacist :-)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian - I meant that Dad called an electric torch a flashlight.

Comment: @rchivers Pharmacist was not in use in the middle-ages, though the root was established in the language at the time. "Dustbin" was original a bin for dust (ashes) from incinerators. "Garbage can" is an update in terms of usage. Your usage of fire doesn't match what I've found in the OED. If you have evidence, please share the links. I'm probably mistaken about boiler, so I'll edit the Q.

Comment: @rchivers Chemist ["looser meaning "dealer in medicinal drugs" (mostly in British English) is from 1745"](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=chemist)

Comment: mm if we have *pharmacian* from 1720 I don't think you can really say *pharmacist* is an AmE neologism. Also no neologism in *garbage can*, which is just descriptive. There is a sense in which *chemist* and *dustbin* are repurposings of an earlier term, which is the other half of what you were saying, but it's not as though *chemist* is used to the exclusion of *pharmacist* in BrE, or that dust does not still go in a dustbin. The use of *garbage* for anything unwanted is itself an extension from the core meaning of *food waste*, so *garbage can* is actually a close parallel of *dustbin*...

Comment: ...*dust* is usually dropped anyway - BrE speakers just put things in the bin or bin them. In light of what Kate Bunting says, *torch/flashlight* has a more complicated history than either of us had assumed. For *electric fire/electric heater*, go to https://www.argos.co.uk/ and look at the images for each product type. The lack of any clear pattern seems to bear out what John Lawler says about dialects not really being distinguished by lexical conservatism, especially when you consider that nobody has done the converse exercise of looking for BrE neologisms corresponding to AmE repurposings.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Thanks. Well well. I never heard that.

Comment: @GArthurBrown - When all cooking was done on fires (open or in a kitchen range), ashes must have made up a large part of household waste.

Comment: (OALD) **garbage can** _noun_  _(NAmE)_ =DUSTBIN // So the term is quite descriptive but not fully so, and has to be defined. Moreover it is clearly a neologism introduced in AmE.

Comment: @LPH it's a can in which you put garbage. I am not seeing a neologism, just an ordinary compound noun.

Comment: @rchivers Isn't every compound noun that is defined in a dictionary a neologism at the very beginning of its use? Taking "garbage collector", for instance, how are we to know what it means without a definition (it can be either a person or a company)? Similarly for "garbage can", it appears obvious but it is not: for instance garbage cans, litter bins  and waste paper baskets are not the same thing; you find garbage cans essentially in kitchens, litter bins in the street, waste paper baskets in offices, yet they are all conceived as receptacles for what is reckoned with as  garbage in the end.

Comment: @LPH No, I wouldn't have said so. If the basic meaning is obvious I don't think that's a new coinage - just a case of using the rules for combining words in basically the same way we do when we put together any sentence. I also think the original question is about coming up with something genuinely new as opposed to working with what we already have, and you undercut that distinction if you say that rearranging what we already have counts as coming up with something new as long as there is some detail that, without any context, you wouldn't guess from the compound term itself.

Comment: @rchivers The point is that from the moment the compound has been recorded in a dictionary ("garbage can" has been recorded (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garbage%20can?src=search-dict-box)) its meaning is_not_ considered as deducible from the separate meanings; in the dictionary shown "garbage can" is  considered as  one noun. //In terms of language, you do come up with something new in passing from "dustbin" to "garbage can"; if you change only "bin" (dustcan) (change  insignificant) you still introduce a neologism (neologism: new word or expression or new meaning of a word).

Comment: @LPH Well, I don't think we're destined to agree on this.

Answer (score 1):

Linguists talk about languages and dialects which are *conservative*, preserving old forms from the ancestral or "parent" languages, or in contrast those which are *innovative* or *advanced* and have new forms different from the ancestral languages.

See the Wikipedia article on [linguistic conservatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_conservatism). There is also a related question on [linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37779/what-is-a-conservative-language).

Comment: The question, though, is about vocabulary—the lexicon.

Comment: @Xanne Apparently the terms are applied to lexicon as well as other elements.

Comment: Sure. Though dialects aren't really distinguished by lexical conservatism much. They tend to vary phonologically more consistently, and there it's hard to find what "conservative" might mean in terms of sound retention and modification. Lexical items are catch-as-catch-can, and every word has its own story in each dialect. Languages, on the other hand, can be very conservative phonologically, as contrast Lithuanian versus Latvian. And German has tended to go for calques like _Fernsehapparat_ instead of borrowing _television._ English and Japanese, by contrast, borrow thousands of words.